# strange ix selection in pandas with duplicate indices

Tags: python, pandas

There is something I dont understand with the `ix` selector in pandas.

Consider the following dataframe

```
dfnu=pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,1,2,3,4],'B':[7,8,9,1,1]},index=list('AABCD'))
```

now look at this output

```
dfnu['A']<2
Out[128]: 
A    False
A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
Name: A, dtype: bool


dfnu['test']=dfnu.ix[dfnu['A']<2,'A']
dfnu
Out[127]: 
   A  B  test
A  7  7     1
A  1  8     1
B  2  9   NaN
C  3  1   NaN
D  4  1   NaN
```

what is going on here? why on earth `test` is equal to 1 on the first row?

Comment: you want to use it this way: `dfnu.ix[dfnu.A < 2, 'test'] = 1` then you will have expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only one row with A<2, `dfnu.ix[dfnu['A'<2, 'A']` has only one value:

```
>>> dfnu.ix[dfnu['A']<2, 'A']
A    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

When you assign this back into dfnu, the values are matched on the index.  In other words, because the one row shown above has `A` as the index, its value (`1`) is assigned to every row in the original DataFrame that has `A` as the index.  This is also why you get NaN for the other rows; since they don't have `A` as the index, no value is assigned for them.

Comment: thank you. but I thought that in the line `dfnu['test']=dfnu.ix[dfnu['A']<2,'A']` values where affected by simple matching row by row. that is, first row on the left side is equal to first row on the left side and so on (no index involved). this is not correct?

Comment: @Noobie: How do you expect that to work when, as in your example, the left side has five rows but the right has only one?

Comment: ok I see. what I had in mind is `dfnu.ix[dfnu['A']<2,'test2']=dfnu.ix[dfnu['A']<2,'A']`. Damn, Pandas is poweful but it gets suble at times ;-)

Comment: @Noobie: Right, you can use boolean indexing if you want to assign only to specific rows selected by position.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
dfnu.ix[dfnu.A < 2, 'test'] = 1
```

Output

```
In [289]: dfnu
Out[289]:
   A  B
A  7  7
A  1  8
B  2  9
C  3  1
D  4  1

In [290]: dfnu.ix[dfnu.A < 2, 'test'] = 1

In [291]: dfnu
Out[291]:
   A  B  test
A  7  7   NaN
A  1  8   1.0
B  2  9   NaN
C  3  1   NaN
D  4  1   NaN
```

it will give you the result you wanted